# How can I get "From Home" and "From Hashtags" from Instagram Graph API Insights endpoint?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

When I hit Instagram Graph API Insights endpoint to get various insights like impressions, reach and engagement, I don't see a fine-grained split of **impressions**. For example look at the following screenshot from android Instagram app:

[image: Instagram Android App post impressions]

Here, there are details called *From Home* and *From Hashtags*.

But I can't see these details in the API response.

### Sample request

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/<post-id>/insights?metric=impressions
```

### Response

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "impressions",
            "period": "lifetime",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": 17
                }
            ],
            "title": "Impressions",
            "description": "Total number of times the media object has been seen",
            "id": "<post-id>/insights/impressions/lifetime"
        }
    ]
}
```

So how can I get the extra details *From Home* and *From Hashtags*?

[Link to Graph API reference page.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/insights#insights)

Answer (score 2):

> So how can I get the extra details From Home and From Hashtags?

Simply put, the [Instagram Graph-API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api) doesn't offer such a feature. The maximum you can do, as you've already included above, is to access the [`impressions` metric](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/insights#metrics) from normal posts, which will return:

> Total number of times the IG Media object has been seen.

Unfortunately, Facebook doesn't enable you to go further in-depth like the mobile app offers you to. There are alternative unofficial APIs, though as the question is specifically tagged as [facebook-graph-api](/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-api), respectively [instagram-graph-api](/questions/tagged/instagram-graph-api), I'll refrain from including those.

*On a slight off-topic note: Not even Facebook (for Facebook themself) offers something similar¹, i.e. breaking down certain data points to the specific degree you're looking for. Thus it's unlikely they got it for Instagram (as the Facebook documentation is better equipped then Instagram).*

---

**1:** To be precise, they offer a [`_source` suffix](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights/#availmetrics) which allows you to break the sources down into groups like Profile, Search, Requests and so forth. Though as mentioned above, that's not the thing you intented to do so.

Comment: Arnold Although my problem is not resolved, thanks for answering.